# Can non-exact battery replacements destroy a laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, hp-pavilion

The battery of my old laptop has died. I have checked the internet shops in Türkiye to buy a new one, and came up with a few close models but not the exact model I need. None of them fully complies with my battery specs, but mAH and Wh values seem close.

- My laptop: **HP Pavilion DV7-2051et**
- My battery specs: **HSTNN-DB75**, 14.4 V, **4860** mAH, **73** Wh

Closest options I have found:

- **HSTNN-IB75**: 14.4 V, 4400 mAH, 48 Wh ~ 49 Wh (and some shops say 63 Wh)
- **HSTNN-DB74**: 14.4 V, 4400 mAH, 63 Wh

Will I do harm to my laptop if I insert one of these batteries in it?

Comment: Two things should be considered:- (1) Does the battery fit physically (same external profile, latches and connectors)? (2) If the battery is the same voltage, it is unlikely to damage the laptop's central electronics, but the charging circuitry is significant: the battery may draw too much current during charging and damage the laptop's charging electronics; or the laptop may deliver too much current and damage the new battery.

Comment: I would advice against it. Too little Wh and you're likely getting random crashes, or the battery will heat up and thus wear down quicker. Too high Wh and the rest of the components will get warmer and may short-burn out.

Comment: @LPChip, no... more Ah just means it will last longer.  As long as the voltage is the same the laptop will still draw exactly the same power and not be any warmer or burn out.  If it is less Ah, then it will last less time... it won't be a problem other than that unless it is significantly lower ( like half or less ).

Comment: @psusi mAH yes, but we're talking about wattage, which is voltage and amps combined.

Comment: @LPChip, and as I said, the laptop will draw the same exact wattage.  Do not confuse wattage ( instantaneous power ) with watt-hours ( total energy over time ).

Comment: @psusi not going to turn this question into an argument, but please read your comment again, it says Ah, not Wh.

Comment: @LPChip, yes... and Wh = Ah * V.  You are confusing that with W = A * V.  The battery determines the Wh; the load determines the A.  A 100 W light bulb can be powered by a 100 V battery that only holds 1 Ah, or a 100 V battery that holds 100 Ah; the only difference is the 100 Ah battery will last approximately 100x longer.  Either way, the light bulb still draws 100 W ( or 1 A ).

Comment: @psusi ah right. thanks for clearing up the confusion.